# How to use two or more csv file in a single feature file in karate?

Tags: csv, ui-automation, karate

I am thinking of using two csv files in a single feature file, but unable to do so, sharing a demo code for the same:

```
Scenario Outline:
* driver 'https://github.com/login'
* input('#login_field', '<username>')
* input('#password', '<password>')
* submit().click("input[name=commit]")
* match html('#js-flash-container') contains 'Incorrect username or password.'

Examples:
|read('one.csv')|
|read('two.csv')|
```

Here, `<username>` is stored in one.csv and `<password>` is stored in two.csv, is there a way we can do this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Karate will never support this. But please note that you can create the data-source in the `Background`.

```
Background:
* def one = read('one.csv')
* def two = read('two.csv')
* def data = karate.append(one, two)

Scenario Outline:
* print __row

Examples:
| data |
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried it but it's running two instances/scenario i.e. once for ```<username>``` and next time for ```<password>```. Whereas the expectation is to get both csv file values in one go.

Comment: @UncleSam look - merging two JSON files into the shape you want is up to you. please do some reading: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms - if you want my personal opinion, please don't even use csv files, just have a normal table in your feature and DON'T over-complicate things. it is up to you now, all the best.

Comment: Do agree @PeterThomas, but using csv is a need as we are getting dynamic data. No worries, Thanks for the help.